# I don't know how to make my matching system work

Tags: python

In my code, I am doing a matching system where you have two lists and the code adds one to a variable for every item in the list that is in the same index and the same item as the other list otherwise it adds one to the other variable it then puts both of the numbers in a list and prints the list.

```
def report(ticket,winner):
kiss = []
Love = []
x = 0
y = 0 
for number in ticket:
    if number in winner:
        x +=1
    elif ticket not in winner:
            y += 1
kiss.append(x)
kiss.append(y)
print kiss
```

an error is like this the input is, report([1,2],[1,2,3]) I want it to add two to the x becuase two of them are in thr correct place and are the same then it needs to add one to the y because its there and not matching but it gives me out: [2,0] also if I put in report([1,3],[1,2,3]) it gives me [2,0] even thoue there not in the same index. That output should be [1,2].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: What is not working in your current code the way you expect?

Comment: It is not looking for a match in the index to make sure that the input is the same as the other it looks to see if it's in the list at all not it the correct placement.

Comment: how are you calling the `report()` function? what are `ticket` and `winner`? can you please provide example inputs?

Comment: for inputs `[1,2]` and `[1,2,3]` why is output `[2,0]` not what you expect? you are appending `x` and `y' to `list` `kiss`. Since `1` and `2` both occur in each list at the same index, `x` gets incremented twice (for the `2`) and `y` never increases because `if number in winner` is always true for those inputs

Comment: also you're getting `[2,0]` even though they are not in the same index because you are not checking indexes, in python the keyword `in` checks if the item is anywhere ***in*** the list, which it is, so you'll need to tell it to check ***by specific index***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logic you describe there are a few problems that your code needs to implement. Mainly, in python the `in` operator checks if an item exists anywhere ***in*** a `list`, so for your examples that will always be `True` and you get that unexpected output.

Instead we want to check each item in the `ticket` list against each item in the `winner` list at the same **index**, so we must specify the index when checking each number.

Try this:

```
def report(ticket,winner):
    kiss = []
    Love = []
    x = 0
    y = 0 

    # because we are checking different length lists, set ticket to longest list
    if len(ticket) > len(winner):
        pass
    elif len(winner) > len(ticket):
        temp = ticket
        ticket = winner
        winner = temp

    for i, number in enumerate(ticket):
        try:
            if winner[i] == number:
                x+=1
            else:
                y+=1
        except IndexError:
            y+=1

    kiss.append(x)
    kiss.append(y)
    print kiss

l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [1,2,3]
report(l1, l2) # prints [2, 1]

l1 = [1,3]
l2 = [1,2,3]
report(l1, l2) # prints [1, 2]
```

Are these your expected outputs?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly shorter version using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
def report(ticket, winner):
    z = sum(1 for x, y in zip(ticket, winner) if x == y)
    return [z, max(len(ticket), len(winner)) - z]
```